# Ruby : How to print out the key and value pair in a hash in the XML format

Tags: ruby, xml, hash

I have a hash which contains several attributes, and I am constantly overriding it with new values for those specific keys. How can I convert the hash into xml, before the next set of values override the hash ?

I tried using the Builder library but I'm getting the error:

> uninitialized constant `Builder::XMLMarkup` (`NameError`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting nested hash into XML using nokogiri](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933451/converting-nested-hash-into-xml-using-nokogiri)

Answer (score 0):

Rails activesupport has a built in method to do this!

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'

hash = { :name => 'bob', :age => '21', :email => 'bob@bob.com'}
hash.to_xml(:root => 'people')
```

Your output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people>  
   <name>bob</name>  
   <age>21</age>  
   <email>bob@bob.com</email>
</people>
```

Comment: Rails was not mentioned and the question is not tagged with rails. You should at least add a `require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'` to this answer.