# Rails convert hash with array to_xml without tags surrounding the array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, xml, hash

I have a hash that contains an array nested a few levels deep:

```
hash = {
    Sender_Name: "Bob",
    Consignement: {
         Load_Type: "FCL",
         JobContainer: [
             {c_number: "123"}, {c_number: 456}
         ]
    }
}
```

And I want to convert it to xml using `to_xml`. The closest I can get to what I want is

```
hash.to_xml(skip_instruct: true, skip_types: true, root: "Consolidation2")
```

which gives me:

```
<Consolidation2>
    <Sender-Name>Bob</Sender-Name>
    <Consignement>
        <Load-Type>FCL</Load-Type>
        <JobContainer>
            <JobContainer>
                <c-number>123</c-number>
            </JobContainer>
            <JobContainer>
                 <c-number>456</c-number>
            </JobContainer>
        </JobContainer>
    </Consignement>
</Consolidation2>
```

But the array of `JobContainer` is wrapped in an extra tag. How can I get it to output this (no extra JobContainer tag wrapping the array):

```
<Consolidation2>
    <Sender-Name>Bob</Sender-Name>
    <Consignement>
        <Load-Type>FCL</Load-Type>
        <JobContainer>
            <c-number>123</c-number>
        </JobContainer>
        <JobContainer>
             <c-number>456</c-number>
        </JobContainer>
    </Consignement>
</Consolidation2>
```

Update 29 May 18:

I ended up going with the suggestion from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27366124/4553162) which gave me what I wanted.

Comment: well that is what xml is about no?

Comment: Yes, well I have to send data to an API and that is the format they want apparently

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27366124), uses  nokogiri and seems to work as you expect. Just change `'root'` into `'Consolidation2'`.

Comment: You probably haven't spotted it yet, or it is not an issue for you, but `Load_Type` was changed into `Load-Type`.

Comment: thanks @iGian that post was what I needed

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try the `xml-simple` [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/xml-simple/versions/1.1.5). I didn't understand what exact output do expect but here is the result:

```
require 'xmlsimple'
=> true
XmlSimple.xml_out(hash, root_name: "Consolidation2")
=> <Consolidation2 Sender_Name="Bob">
     <Consignement Load_Type="FCL">
       <JobContainer c_number="123" />
       <JobContainer c_number="456" />
     </Consignement>
   </Consolidation2>
```

You can also take a look at the [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/2.1.2/XmlSimple) for more options.